# jquery .hover() same effect for different elements

Tags: jquery

I have this scenario:

html:

```
<a>text</a>
<a>text</a>
<a>text</a>
<a>text</a>

<h4>hi there</h4>
<h4>hi there</h4>
<h4>hi there</h4>
<h4>hi there</h4>
```

javascript:

```
$("h4").hide();
$('a').hover(function () {
  $("h4").addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);
},
function () {
  $("h4").stop(0,0)
     .queue(function(){ $("h4").removeClass('hover').fadeOut(300).dequeue() });
});
```

​css:

```
.hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

this is jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/zS6ex/280/

i want that when i hover mouse on a single a single is displayed not all

thanks

​

Comment: for which "one" you want to add it..??

Comment: Could you please translate this "when i hover the moves h4 displays for each. i want that when i hover mouse on a single a single is displayed not all" to english? I have no idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try my fiddle to see if it match your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some data to find the target of anchor links. Note that anchor links should have href attributes.

```
<a href='#first'>text</a>
<a href='#second'>text</a>
<a href='#third'>text</a>
<a href='#fourth'>text</a>

<h4 id='first'>hi there</h4>
<h4 id='second'>hi there</h4>
<h4 id='third'>hi there</h4>
<h4 id='fourth'>hi there</h4>
```

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    $(this.hash).addClass('hover').stop().fadeIn(300);
}, function() {
    $(this.hash).stop().fadeOut(300).removeClass('hover')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CywgQ/

Comment: i problem. how to use this code if i have this situation 

<a href="#content-management-system" id="cms" class="cms hov" title="Content Management System">
                <li> <img src="images/services page graphics/CMS DEVELOPMENT.jpg" width="198" height="148" alt="" class="serv_img"><img src="images/spinner.gif" width="16" height="16" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
                  <h4 class="headh">Content Management System </h4>
                </li>
                </a>

Comment: @user1450479 Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: i want to display h4 when i hover the mouse on a

Comment: @user1450479 You can use selector context, this way you don't need IDs http://jsfiddle.net/eWhT3/

Comment: @undefined.. tell me your twitter/facebook/website/blog or something

Comment: @user1450479 You are welcome :), my website is http://www.htmlpack.com and my email address webozine@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

The `h4` is not a child of `a` element and there is no connection between your `a` and your `h4`.

Try maybe to give them an `ID` or something to target the correct `h4` otherwise you can do something like that...

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('h4').eq(i).addClass('hover');            
});​
```

Here a **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBSmq/1/)** with an improvement on hovering and `.toggleClass()`.

Comment: if you want it to fade: [http://jsfiddle.net/BBSmq/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/BBSmq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You should not `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut`. It won't be accessible in the ViewPort. Use `opacity` and animate.

```
$("h4").css("opacity", 0);
$("h4").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover").animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover").animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
});​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zS6ex/288/

Answer (score 0):

I have done complete bins for above query. here is  demo link...

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp77

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    Link-1
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    Link-2
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    Link-3
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    Link-4
  </a>
  <h4>
    hi there...Header 1
  </h4>
  <h4>
    hi there...Header 2
  </h4>
  <h4>
    hi there...Header 3
  </h4>
  <h4>
    hi there...Header 4
  </h4>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("h4").fadeOut();
    $('a').hover(function() {
        $("h4:eq(" + $(this).index() + ")").addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);
    }, function() {
        $("h4:eq(" + $(this).index() + ")").removeClass('hover').fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
a{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background:#3A3A3A;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
a:hover{
  background:#9C9C9C;
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:#262626;
}

h4{
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #4455bd;
  margin-left:10px;

  width:300px;
  padding:2px;
  background:#a3c4fd;
}
h4.hover{
  background:#ffdf88;
}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp77

If you want to check effect without fadeOut(), then check jQuery changes on demo link as given below.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp77/2